# Best way to store event times in (My)SQL database

Tags: mysql, time

I'm trying to decide on the best way to store event times in a MySQL database. These should be as flexible as possible and be able to represent "single events" (starts at a certain time, does not necessarily need an end time), "all day" and "multi day" events, repeating events, repeating all day events, possibly "3rd Saturday of the month" type events etc.

Please suggest some tried and proven database schemes.

Comment: What have you chosen as best solution in the past for this problem? I'm also looking for a database scheme for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Table: Events

- StartTime (dateTime)
- EndTime (dateTime)   null for no end time
- RepeatUnit (int) null = noRepeat, 1 = hour, 2 = day, 3 = week, 4 = dayOfMonth, 5 = month, 6 = year
- NthDayOfMonth (int)
- RepeatMultiple (int)     eg, set RepeatUnit to 3, and this to 2 for every fortnight
- Id   - if required, StartTime might be suitable for you to uniquely identify an event.
- Name (string) - name given to the event, if required

This might help. It would require a decent amount of code to interpret when the repeats are. Parts of the time fields that are at lower resolutions than the repeat unit would have to be ignored. Doing the 3rd saturday of the month woudln't be easy either... the NthDayOfMonth info would be required just for doing this kind of functionality.

The database schema required for this is simple in comparison with the code required to work out where repeats fall.

Comment: How'd you store an all-day event with this? I'd definitely want to separate date and time, as '24-12-2008 00:00:00' is ambiguous...

Comment: StartTime = '24-12-2008 00:00:00'   EndTime = '24-12-2008 23:59:59'  if an all-day event is treated as a special case by your application, then the code that accesss the database would have to know a start of 00:00:00 and end of 23:59:59 meant something special, check for them and set an allDay flag

Comment: Or add the column  allDay (int) as was mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

I worked on a planner application which loosely follows the iCalendar standard (to record events). You may want to read [RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445) or this schema published by Apple Inc. [icalendar schema](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SyncServicesSchemaRef/Articles/Calendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001540-CJBEHAAG) to see if they are relevant to the problem.

My database schema (recurring/whole-day event was not considered at the time)

```
event (event_id, # primary key
       dtstart,
       dtend,
       summary,
       categories,
       class,
       priority,
       summary,
       transp,
       created,
       calendar_id, # foreign key
       status,
       organizer_id, # foreign key
       comment,
       last_modified,
       location,
       uid);
```

the foreign key `calendar_id` in the previous table refers this

```
calendar(calendar_id, # primary key
         name);
```

while `organizer_id` refers this (with other properties like common name etc. missing)

```
organizer(organizer_id, # primary key
          name);
```

Another documentation that you may find more readable is located [here](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/)

hope this helps

Comment: The link to the icalendar schema seems to have changed. Could you try to update it?

Comment: i think u can still look for rfc2445 :)

Comment: @svish just found an updated link to the (now deprecated) iCalendar schema, not sure if you still need it though

Comment: @Jeffrey94 I do not, but please update your answer in case anyone else does (or I do later at some point ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need two tables. One for storing the repeating events (table repeatevent) and one for storing the events (table event). Simple entries are only stored in the event table. Repeating entries are stored in the repeatevent table and all single entries for the repeating event are also stored in the event table. This means that everytime you enter a repeating entry, you have to enter all the single resulting entries. You can do this by using triggers, or as part of your business logic.

The advantage of this approach is, that querying events is simple. They are all in the event table. Without the storage of repeating events in the event table, you would have complex SQL or business logic that would make your system slow.

```
create table repeatevent (
id int not null auto_increment, 
type int, // 0: daily, 1:weekly, 2: monthly, ....
starttime datetime not null, // starttime of the first event of the repetition
endtime datetime, // endtime of the first event of the repetition
allday int, // 0: no, 1: yes
until datetime, // endtime of the last event of the repetition
description varchar(30)
)

create table event (
id int not null auto_increment,
repeatevent null references repeatevent, // filled if created as part of a repeating event
starttime datetime not null,
endtime datetime,
allday int,
description varchar(30)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way the [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Fields) does it? Recording both start and end time that way.

Comment: No, more like iCal. I just haven't found a readable description yet of how iCal does things exactly or how to best express this in SQL.

Answer (score -2):

Use datetime and mysql's built in NOW() function. Create the record when the process starts, update your column that tracks the end time when it the process ends.